# Replacing null values with join

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have two tables

```
      Table1:                                Table2:
ID:      Type:     Amount:               ID:       Amount:
165      Red         300                 188       425           
167      Red         100                 189       500 
168      Blue        250                 222       129
188      Grey        NULL                333       247 
189      Grey        NULL                369       328
```

I am trying to replace the null values from table 1 by joining on table 2.

My code results in two amount columns.

```
LEFT JOIN table2 
ON table2.pk = table1.pk
AND table1.Type IS NULL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want:

```
select t1.id, t1.type, coalesce(t1.amount, t2.amount)
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t1.id = t2.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps for your needs

```
select t1.id,t1.type,isnull(t1.amount,t2.amount) 'Amount' from table1 t1 left join  table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

you can use **isnull() function** so that if the first table amount is null then it will take second table value.